# Geth sync stuck on a block

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, mining, synchronization

I'm running the go-ethereum node with geth on my server. It sync the blocks in the beginning smoothly but after some time it stuck on a block from last two days. Any help will be appreciated.

eth.blockNumber:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"0x424686"}
```

eth.syncing:

```
 {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":{"currentBlock":"0x424686"‌​,"highestBlock":"0x4‌​417ca","knownStates"‌​:"0x23c865","pulledS‌​tates":"0x23c865","s‌​tartingBlock":"0x424‌​686"}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying _stuck_?

Comment: I mean it stop on a single block while syncing.

Comment: What the output of `eth.blockNumber` and `eth.syncing` console command?

Comment: For eth.blockNumber

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":"0x424686"}
and for eth.syncing
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":{"currentBlock":"0x424686","highestBlock":"0x4417ca","knownStates":"0x23c865","pulledStates":"0x23c865","startingBlock":"0x424686"}}

Comment: Are you using the `--fast` option?, I assume that can be a problem with your IPS provider, check the peers cound and net settings of the `geth`.

Comment: I'm not using the --fast option, Is it fine to use this option for implementing every action on the node??

Comment: The `--fast` option is about the synchronization process, that option make sync process of the database much faster. I suggest you to clear datadir and start sync process again `geth --fast --cache=1024`.

Comment: I'm using geth command with --fast ==cache=1024 after clear datadir, it again stop on "0x42ae50" block. I don't know what happening with this. Any help please.

Comment: What is in the logs? is it still sync database? is the `eth.syncing` returns result?

Comment: eth.syncing returns {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":83,"result":{"currentBlock":"0x42ae50","highestBlock":"0x4447fc","knownStates":"0x0","pulledStates":"0x0","startingBlock":"0x42ae40"}}

Comment: as long as `eth.syncing` doesn't returns `false` your database is syncing.

Comment: Then why that block taking so long time to sync, any idea??

Comment: @RahulSati I see that your issue is almost a year old. Currently I have the same issue on testnet. Did you solve it and how?